# Error TLSSocket.onConnectSecure trying to send Email from Hotmail with Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, rest, nodemailer

I am trying to use nodemailer with hotmail to send Email.  testing from postman i am getting this as Error:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.1348]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

D:\node_apps\subscription-api>node subApp.js
App running on Port: 8080
D:\node_apps\subscription-api\subApp.js:139
        if(error) throw error;
                  ^

Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1514:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:936:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:708:12) {
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  command: 'CONN'
}

D:\node_apps\subscription-api>
```

My code is looking thus:

```
app.get('/api/v1/sendsubexpnotice/:email',function(req,res){
    let email = req.params.email;
    if(!email){
        return res.status(400).send({error: true, message: 'Please provide E-mail'});
    }
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service:'hotmail',
        auth:{
            user: 'xxxxxxxxxx@hotmail.com',
            pass: 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
        }
    });
    const mailOptions = {
        from :'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@hotmail.com',
        to: email,
        subject: 'Your Subscription is about to Expire!',
        text : 'Your Subscription is about to Expire!'
    };
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,function(error,info){
        if(error) throw error;
        return res.send({error:false, data: results, message: 'OK'});
    })
})
```

What do I do to resolve such error?
How do i get this to send email? kindly advice.

Comment: So which line is "subApp.js:139" referring to? I really doubt that hotmail serves a self-signed certificate ...

Comment: tried the same for gail,the same trouble

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it.
just did some few minor changes

Code looks like so

```
app.get('/api/v1/sendsubexpnotice/:email',function(req,res){
    let email = req.params.email;
    if(!email){
        return res.status(400).send({error: true, message: 'Please provide E-mail'});
    }
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service:'gmail',
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port:'587',
        auth:{
            user: '****@gmail.com',
            pass: '****'
        },
        secureConnection: 'false',
        tls: {
            ciphers: 'SSLv3',
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    });
    const mailOptions = {
        from :'****@gmail.com',
        to: email,
        subject: 'Your Subscription is about to Expire!',
        text : 'Your Subscription is about to Expire!'
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,function(error,info){
        if(error)throw error;
        return res.send({error:false, data: info, message: 'OK'});
    })
})
```